# Timer with MATLAB GUI is not refreshing GUI?

Tags: matlab, function, loops, user-interface, timer

I had timer in my original script which worked fine and it re-ran my script every 60 seconds.

I've now moved the same script into a GUI using GUIDE and i've literally pasted it into the GUI code which GUIDE provides and it works fine. But when I include the timer code from the original script it doesn't work and it displays this error whenever I run it:

```
??? Error using ==> axes
Invalid object handle

Error in ==>
SoftwareMonitoringToolGUI>SoftwareMonitoringToolGUI_OpeningFcn at 100
axes(handles.axes5);

Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 221
    feval(gui_State.gui_OpeningFcn, gui_hFigure, [],
    guidata(gui_hFigure), varargin{:});

Error in ==> SoftwareMonitoringToolGUI at 51
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
```

My GUI looks like this and it stays the same regardless of whether or not the timer code is included in the script i.e MATLAB still builds it. The difference is that MATLAB provides the above error when I include the timer code:

[image]
When I simply remove the timer code only, it works again (but without the refresh feature I need using the timer). My handles are correct because MATLAB is generating my figures in the GUI window.

Timer code, placed at the start of the GUI code:

```
function SoftwareMonitoringToolGUI_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
handles.output = hObject;



guidata(hObject, handles);

%                  ***TIMER FUNCTION***
%**************************************************************************
% 
Period = 60; % Update period in seconds

tim = timer('Period', Period, 'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate',...
    'TimerFcn', 'SoftwareMonitoringToolGUI');

start(tim)

stop(tim)
```

I want the timer to refresh the GUI every 60 seconds. The reason for this is that new data is calculated every time my script is executed. Thoughts?

Comment: The problem looks like it's in the scope of the function the timer is calling.  Script vs. GUI (function) can be different in this regard. You'll have to provide more details - actually, a smaller test case that you can post in its entirety would be best. You will probably figure out the answer by creating such a test case, come to think of it.

Comment: What if I designed the timer definition here as a function and included it at the very top of my script. i.e `function timer = code I inserted above` how could I do that? I think I understand what you mean. I will revise my post and try to provide more details of what is happening in the code and perhaps some images.

Comment: Appended the thread to include an image of the GUI for completeness. Let me know what other details you may require.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a string to `timer` as the callback, `MATLAB` calls that string as executable code.  So, what you are doing here:

```
tim = timer('Period', Period, 'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate',...
'TimerFcn', 'SoftwareMonitoringToolGUI');
```

is equivalent to calling

```
exec('SoftwareMonitoringToolGui');
```

or alternatively

```
SoftwareMonitoringToolGui;
```

with no arguments.  You haven't provided enough code to know exactly what's going on, but I'm guessing that `SoftwareMonitoringToolGui` is the name of your gui function. This means that your gui attempting to spawning a different instance of the same code, but without passing arguments.  If this isn't how it is designed to work, you have problems.

What you probably want to do instead is create an update function (additional function in the same file as the gui code), and pass a handle to that function to the timer:

```
tim = timer('Period', Period, 'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate',...
'TimerFcn', @updateFcn);
```

Comment: Could you render an example of what you mean or even manipulate my code? The timer doesn't need any inputs other than the value which it should be run for, which is statically set at 60. Basically the timers only purpose is to execute everything in my script again every 60 seconds indefinitely. I.e the GUI window will re-open/update every 60 seconds. The reason for this is that my eternal script code is working with real-time data so the script fetches and calculates new external data and the timer merely tells the script to do it all again every 60 seconds.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your gui code before the timer happens. Try calling the function `SoftwareMonitoringToolGui` on the debugger command line. See what happens.

Comment: Could I not just turn the code I have for the timer into a function definition and place it at the start of the whole script before the other functions which contain the rest of my user-defined code? I'm unsure about breakpoints as i'm fairly new to MATLAB/coding.

Comment: I suggest googling `debugging matlab`. As far as setting a breakpoint, click next to the line number in the editor on the line you want to have the debugger stop on. A salmon-colored dot should appear. When it stops there, you will be able to test stuff on the command line and see the state of all the variables that exist in that scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to pass `handles` array as a param to your function in order to update your GUI controls. To do so, create timer in the following manner:

```
tim = timer('Period', Period, 'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate',...
'TimerFcn', {@SoftwareMonitoringToolGUI, handles});
```

To make such timer work, you need to update `SoftwareMonitoringToolGUI` signature like this:

```
function SoftwareMonitoringToolGUI(obj,event,handles)
```